# How heavy is the process of converting back and forth between NSData and NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-uri

I'm thinking about handling all types of media in my app using [data uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

For example I want to represent a video recording as data-uri and pass it back and forth different modules. I've been using NSData to do it but I want to make it more cross platform so this is what I came up with.

This is the code I'm using to convert NSData to a NSString that conforms to data-uri format:

```
NSData* mediaData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
NSString* dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@", [mediaData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
NSURL* dataURI = [NSURL URLWithString:dataString];
```

I can sacrifice a little bit of performance for the value I'm getting out of this, but I'm not sure how much of a performance load this will be.

Would you recommend something like this? How much performance hit would this bring? I would appreciate any kind of insights.

Comment: What does this have to do with NSString?

Comment: A key question is really about memory usage...

Comment: I'm asking how much load converting back and forth between NSData and NSString (data-uri format) introduces. Am I mistaken? I don't understand why you are even trying to close this question.

Comment: Personally, I'd suspect that the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` is likely to be more computationally intensive than the creation of the data URI with the base 64 string. If you built this image dynamically, it's hard to get around that, but if the image was from some existing asset, sometimes avoiding the round trip through a `UIImage` and instead grab the raw asset can help. But capture the `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` between each of these steps and you'll be able to calculate the amount of time each step takes.